# How to make js-generated xml file be in utf-8

Tags: javascript, html, xml, utf-8, data-uri

I generate some xml in-browser and set it as data-uri for a link.
When I click the link it is opened, but contents is recognized as ASCII and the text is garbled.

How do I make the content of the generated file be utf-8?

The xml starts with prolog `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>` but this doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

So the answer is rather straightforward. 
I added the BOM mark `\uFEFF` to the beginning of the generated file and it worked fine. It looks tike this:

```
    \uFEFF<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> ...
```